# Get table name by constraint name

Tags: oracle, constraints

Oracle constraint name is known.

How do I find the name of the table for which this constraint is applied?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_constraints
 WHERE constraint_name = <<your constraint name>>
```

will give you the name of the table.  If you don't have access to the `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` view, `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` or `USER_CONSTRAINTS` should work as well.

Comment: not working, getting error "Invalid object name 'USER_CONSTRAINTS'". please help.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi - `select table_name from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'xxx';` should work for any user.  Are you sure you don't have a typo in your query? What does `select owner, object_name from all_objects where object_name = 'USER_CONSTRAINTS'` return for you?

Comment: Add owner name in the query too...

SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_constraints
 WHERE constraint_name = <<your constraint name>>
and owner = <<OwnerName>>

Answer (score 18):

`ALL_CONSTRAINTS` describes constraint definitions on tables accessible to the current user.

`DBA_CONSTRAINTS` describes all constraint definitions in the database.

`USER_CONSTRAINTS` describes constraint definitions on tables in the current user's schema

```
Select CONSTRAINT_NAME,CONSTRAINT_TYPE ,TABLE_NAME ,STATUS from 
USER_CONSTRAINTS;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, column_name
from user_constraints natural join user_cons_columns
where table_name = "my_table_name";
```

will give you what you need

Comment: this answer is from known table name to return constraint name, question says contraint name is known need to get table name